# EXCEL VBA: opening XLSM excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel

i cant figure out my error in my codes

```
If cboUnit.Text = "MARINER" Then
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UNIT" & "\MARINER"
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Workbooks("TOUKEI DATA REPORT GRAPHING").Close
End If
```

i just want to open xlsm file which is on the folder unit
but i always got an error:

runtime error '1004'
the file this getting is 'xlsx' extension

Comment: FWIW, that code appears to work. I just right-clicked `Copy as path` a macro-enabled workbook from my Documents folder and pasted that into your code then removed `.xlsm` from the string. Worked fine.

Comment: Have you tried to add the extension to the path like `"\MARINER\filenam.xlsm"`?

Comment: i got it i omit "\" before the MARINER and add the "\" after the UNIT :D

Comment: `Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UNIT" & "\MARINER"` this doesn't look like a path to a file but rather to a folder... What's the file name?

Comment: the filename is MARINER it is an macro-enabled excel file

Comment: Just to be clear, you have MARINER.xlsx and MARINER.xlsm in the same folder and you want to open MARINER.xlsm?

Comment: Unrelated, but is there a specific reason you are using "\UNIT" & "\MARINER" instead of "\UNIT\MARINER"?

Comment: Two questions:  You said you got it.  1.  Do you still need help?  If not, post your own answer.  2. If you define the entire address of the file before you call 'Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:= filePath'  Set filePath as a string and concatenate the path and filename with extension.  You can look at the Locals Window or print a MsgBox to see that the value is correct.  You should be able to see any problems from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you use something like this, it should at least make debugging simpler.  Then substitute the code I've provided with this line:

```
Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UNIT" & "\MARINER"
```

Declare the variables with your other variables.  I'm understanding your question to be that "Mariner" is the file name.  If it's not, you will need to change the fileNPath.

```
Dim path As String, fileNPath As String

'add these two values above your code
path = ActiveWorkbook.path
fileNPath = path & "\UNIT\MARINER.xlsm"

Application.Workbooks.Open fileName:=fileNPath   'Change this line
```

Once you've done this, you can see the values for the file path in debug mode where the version you have won't have a value until the line that isn't working anyway.  So this way, you can SEE what is going on before you try to USE it.

**note:**  To have a macro enabled workbook, it must be .xlsm, not .xlsx